# Network operation every half sec

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to make network operation in every 1sec and depending on data, i want to update the ListView continuously.

Following is my approach:
Using thread and `handler.postDelayed`, it makes the network request every sec and update only those views of the row in `ListView` which needs to be updated. It does not update `ListView` using `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

Though it updates the UI, but it takes time in updating the UI. Is it because, I am using emulator?

Is this the right approach for this scenario? Any other best approach for this?

Comment: My first thoughts on this are that it's going to drain battery something fierce; also, it's possible (and likely) that your network request may not return before the next request arrives. 1 second is a VERY fast refresh amount. Is it really necessary to refresh that frequently?

Comment: Thanks kcoppock. It is one of the requirement of the application. And this service starts in background only when corresponding activity is created and stops when corresponding activity pause so it will be upto the user how much to be into that activity.

About network request may not return before next request arrives, I am using the timestamp which comes in json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I would take is to have a dedicated service in my application; that service would start a thread to sit in a loop: sleep 1 second; perform the network request; post the results (if any).

The emulator can be very slow, depending on your system and the Android version you're emulating. For me, with high end hardware, it seems emulating 2.2 is faster than 2.3, and that's much faster than 3.0.

Comment: Right now I am creating new thread for every network request. Is this approach correct?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Creating a new thread is a relatively expensive operation -- much more expensive than just sleeping. For something that doesn't happen all that often (or happens at unpredictable times) it's normal. For a regularly scheduled event that happens this frequently, creating a new thread is not the correct approach.